# Full factorial design (Anova with/without covariate): unusual results

Tags: anova, ancova, predictor

I’m doing a research about attribute’s reviews effect on credibility and intentions, when I perform Anova without covariates, I get no significant results. On the other hand, main effects are all significant when I put some continuous measured variables as covariates. (eg. Familiarity, expertise, implication etc.) I ask for that because usually it is the reverse. If not, can someone gives me an explanation or some bibliographic references to justify this. In other words, is it right to perform directly an Ancova with bypassing the first step (Anova without control variables) ?

Second question is about the way to control demographics, $\chi^2$ tests show no significant differences between groups  in term of  demographics (age, sex…etc).  Is it right to tell that its a sufficient condition to not integrate demographics in Ancova test ? considering that demographics ares not variables of interest. 
Looking forward to your help!

Edit:
@utobi
find a part of answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/86763/perform-an-ancova-only-if-one-way-anova-proves-statistical-significance?rq=1) but Still no justification (réf) 
and nothing about comparing groups

So, I measured the impact of “Length” (long-short) and “Valence” (positive-negative) of reviews on “credibility” (7 likert points scale), Anova showed no main effects of those factors on credibility. in my survey, I also measured “familiarity with the reviews” and “implication on purchased products”. when I put those two variables as covariates, Ancova tests showed a strong main effect of length and valence on credibility.
IV: review attributes DV credibility Cov: familiarity and Implication :

About demographics: I have about (60% males / 40% females) for each group

And about 55% more than 30 Y old / 45% less than 30 for each group Differences between groups in term of age and sex are not sig accordint to $\chi^2$ tests.

Comment: Can you provide a replicable example?

Comment: May be your covariates accounted for some of the noise.